# Proto3 JSON not converting field name to camelCase

Tags: go, grpc, protoc

Prot3 documentation says that by default JSON printer should convert the field name to lowerCamelCase and use that as the JSON name, but I did not observe this in my files:

```
Lng float32 `protobuf:"fixed32,1,opt,name=Lng,proto3" json:"Lng,omitempty"`
Lat float32 `protobuf:"fixed32,2,opt,name=Lat,proto3" json:"Lat,omitempty"`
```

```
message Coordinate {
    float Lng = 1;
    float Lat = 2;
}
```

Is there an explicit syntax that would do this? I am using `protoc-gen-go v1.25.0` and `protoc v3.13.0`

Comment: please share this part of your `proto` file.

Comment: @ttrasn I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with my `Proto`s. so I found the solution is in the name of variables, you should change your proto message variables to this :

```
message Coordinate {
    float lng = 1;
    float lat = 2;
}
```

the protobuf generates this :

```
Lng float32 `protobuf:"fixed32,1,opt,name=lng,proto3" json:"lng,omitempty"`
Lat float32 `protobuf:"fixed32,2,opt,name=lat,proto3" json:"lat,omitempty"`
```

if you have a multi-word variable, you should change it to this:

```
    float location_lat = 1;
```

so the generated result will be :

```
LocationLat float32 `protobuf:"fixed32,1,opt,name=location_lat,proto3" json:"location_lat,omitempty"`
```

Comment: This works. I did not use this because I presumed that then the Go variables would be lowercase and therefore not exported. It is not the case as I see.